# LaTeX said that \end{titlepage} is undefined

Tags: errors

I don't understand why but since this afternoon i can't compile my doc because Overleaf says that `\end{titlepage}` and `\newpage` are undefined in my document. Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{subfigure,color,soul}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}         % pour d\'efinir plus de couleurs
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
         \begin{center}
            \Huge{\textbf{Manuel d'Utilisation :\\ Montage et programmation d'une main robotisée}}\vskip 2cm
                \LARGE{\textbf{Albaladejo Joris}}\vskip 2cm
                \Large {\textbf{ Association 1901 \textit{Robots !}}}\vskip0.5cm
                 %\vskip 4cm
                \Large{\textbf{Janvier 2021}}\vskip3cm
                \includegraphics[]{Images_main/logo_asso.png}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%\newpage \thispagestyle{empty}
        %\null
        \tableofcontents
        \newpage
        \listoffigures
        \newpage


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\input{Déroulé/Jour_1/Jour1}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\input{Déroulé/Jour_2/Jour2}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\input{Déroulé/Jour_3/Jour3}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\input{Déroulé/Jour_4}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated : `\Large` does not take arguments

Comment: The errir message I get upon trying to compile your document is `! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@pagetransition ...orighyper@pagetransition 
                                                  \mm@pageadditionalaction` which seems to be caused by the combination of `multimedia` and `hyperref`. What do you want to use the `multimedia` package for?

Comment: Also unrelated, but you might want to consider replacing the deprrcated `subfigure` package with either `subfig` or `subcaption`. Also, make sure, you don't load packages more than once. (e.g. `xcolor` extends `color`, so no need to load `color` if you already use `xcolor`.)

Comment: load `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\usepackage{multimedia}`